# Adding dates in a range

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, range

I need to add dates from 01-01-2011 to 31-12-2014 in format: dd-mm-yyyy, how can I do this? I mean something like this:

```
SET @Date = '01/01/2011';
WHILE @Date <'31/12/2014'
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Calendar(DataKal) VALUES (@Date);
    SET @Date = @Date + 1;
END
```

I am using SQL Server 2014.

Comment: Have you checked out the SQL Server date functions e.g. `dateadd`?

Comment: What do you mean "Add dates"? Also, date and time data types don't have a format; if your dates have a format they are, by definition, *not* a date and time data type.

Comment: Learn the power and utility of a tally table (aka numbers table) - as Larnu has posted. Stop thinking in terms of RBAR loops; start thinking in terms of sets. SQL code will generally be far more efficient when you approach it from a set perspective.

Answer (score 4):

If what you are saying is you want to `INSERT` a row for each date between 2 dates then the best, and by far fastest, method to do this is with a Tally:

```sql
DECLARE @StartDate date = '20110101',
        @EndDate date = '20141230'; --Seems odd you want to omit 31 December 2014

WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1)
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1 AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4) --10,000 rows
INSERT INTO dbo.Calendar (DataKal) 
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, T.I, @StartDate)
FROM Tally T;
```

Comment: My tests were pretty inconclusive on that, @Charlieface . [1](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6f50dc1293cf0996af0b102470d614bf), [2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=173031b15a765219ce7cc46851d2967c)

Comment: I did say "might", I think you need to up the rownumbers to start seeing a difference. Itzik went into detail on this with mine and others' help  https://sqlperformance.com/2021/01/t-sql-queries/number-series-solutions-1

Comment: Yeah, it's probably never going to be a problem with dates, @Charlieface . Dates *and* times, or just a numbers possibly. Considering that 100,000 days is more than any of our lifetimes we're probably "safe" for a calendar table. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive CTE to define the dates and load them:

```
with cte as (
      select convert(date, '2011-01-01') as dte
      union all
      select dateadd(day, 1, dte)
      from cte
      where dte < '2014-12-31'
     )
insert into calendar (datakal)
    select dte
    from cte
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

Note that this inserts the date using the *internal* format.  If you want to see it in a particular format -- such as dd-mm-yyyy -- then you can add a second column.  I would suggest adding the column as a computed column:

```
alter table calendar add dd_mm_yyyy as (convert(varchar(10), datakal, 105));
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c47077f2301c83ee74fe0237cf148d59) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I recommend against this method; it'll be quite slow for the number of rows the OP is after

Comment: @Larnu . . . Are you actually recommending a `while` loop instead?

Comment: No, that's even worse. A set based solution like a Tally is *way* faster. As I have recommended on many of your other answers.

Comment: An rCTE that you've copy-pasta'd again and again and again, and we keep telling you: it's slow, stop promoting it. Use a tally function instead.

Comment: Less than a second is an age on a busy OLTP server, and executed many times a second is going to be slow. Now go and have a look at the other hundreds of cases where it is used in an apply or a join, and have a look at the perf on that. The idea is to promote *good* solutions that work everywhere, not just one that happens to work in this case because reasons. Standard methods: I don't know, I read [Itzik Ben-Gan](https://sqlperformance.com/2021/03/t-sql-queries/number-series-solutions-3) and [Jeff Moden](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/hidden-rbar-counting-with-recursive-ctes), ....

Comment: .... they would run a mile from a rCTE. And you'll survive a single downvote: 1101445 - 2 = 1101443 so don't get too worried, it's just my opinion.